# Интерфейс Delphi XE - отображение доп.окна Code Explorer

Tags: ide, delphi-xe

В Delphi 7 была такая замечательная функция, как `View` → `Code Explorer` это  доп.окно к главному окну редактора кода.
Оно ещё вызывалась комбинацией `Shift+Ctrl+E`. В нём можно было увидеть все переменные, функции и процедуры открытого модуля.

Есть ли такая функция в Delphi XE? И как её отобразить, если есть?

Answer (score 1):

В Delphi XE оно называется `Structure` (`Shift+Alt+F12`)

Comment: Про это окошко `Structure` я знал, но почему-то в нём я не могу найти свои, собственноручно написанные работающие процедуры и функции. Т.е. оно у меня их не отображает. Оно отображает лишь элементы накинутые на форму. И переменных там тоже нет.

Comment: @I_CaR, а если перейти с вкладки `Design` на вкладку `Code` (`F12`)?

Comment: в нём всё та же статичная картина, лишь компоненты, которые присутствуют на форме и более ни чего. Хоть `Design` хоть `Code`.

Answer (score 0):

В справке Delphi 10.2 указан порядок Tools > Options > Delphi Options > Explorer. Последний пункт отсутсвует. Тогда поможет решение от партнера Embarcadero http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html решение не бесплатное.